# scrolling a UIScrollView on the click of a button

Tags: uiscrollview

I would like to know if it is possible for me to scroll a UIScrollView on the click of a UIButton, and if so, would someone be able to tell me how to.

I am currently using the below code to see if in the scrollview more content is there to its left and if it is there, display an image which would tell the users that there is more content if they scroll to the left.
I would like to implement a functionality where I add a UIButton instead of the image and when more content is available on the left and when the user clicks the button, the scrollview would scroll to its left.

Code:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView1 
  {
       if (scrollView1.contentOffset.x == scrollView1.contentSize.width -                       scrollView1.frame.size.width) 
        {        
            // reached the right
             self.imageView.hidden = YES;
        }
        else
        {
             self.imageView.hidden = NO;
        }
  }
```

It would be great if someone could help me out on this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [scrolling a UIScrollView on the click of a button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388486/scrolling-a-uiscrollview-on-the-click-of-a-button)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily make the scrollview scroll by using the scrollRectToVisible:animated: of UIScrollView. You just have to enter the rectangle where you want it to scroll and use YES for animated. For instance:

```
[yourScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(10,10,100,100) animated:YES];
```

Comment: Question, If I have a ScrollMenu.h and ScrollView.m file where I add the above in a fucntion for when i need the view scrolled, how can I acceess (or call) that function in the ScrollView.m file from a function in the example myprogViewController.m file?

Answer (score 0):

You could also try `setContentOffset`, just like this:

```
[yourScrollView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(0, 0) animated: YES]
```

Simply call this method in the IBAction of your button. Replace the `yourScrollView` with the UIScrollView instance you created yourself. This will automatically scroll your scrollView to the left.

Hope this may help.